# Unix addition script

Tags: shell-script, command

Im currently trying to make a addition command in unix and have come up with the following code:

```
#! /bin/bash
#! Add - adds two given numbers together and displays the result

"$num1" = $1
"$num2" = $2

echo "Enter two numbers"
        read num1 num2
        sum=$(“$num1” + “$num2”)
                echo "The sum is = $sum"
```

This however does not work.

Comment: Those look like "smart quotes" which wouldn't work if that's accurate.  Aside from that what about it "does not work"?

Comment: When i first run the command it displays
./add: line 5: : command not found
./add: line 6: : command not found
Enter two numbers
and when i add the two numbers it displays
2 2
./add: line 10: “2”: command not found
The sum is =

Comment: `num1=$1`. No spaces, and the undecorated name on the left-hand side of the equal sign. Of course, those assignments are unnecessary, because you overwrite their values with the `read1 statement before you ever use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`((...))` is the way to do arithmetic, not single parens, and you don't need quotes there  Try:

```
sum=$((num1+num2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the syntax errors in the script, it looks like the two numbers are *given*, i.e. they are present on the script's command line.

That means that the script could be reduced to

```
#!/bin/sh

printf 'The sum of %d and %d is %d\n' "$1" "$2" "$(( $1 + $2 ))"
```

This obviously does no verification of the passed arguments whatsoever.  For example, it does not verify that there are exactly *two* arguments, and it also does not verify that they are decimal integers.

The script would be used as

```
$ ./script.sh -23 32
The sum of -23 and 32 is 9
```